# Firebase remove specific in a the field

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to react native, I'm trying to delete a specific field but having issue

[image: Firebase]

I'm trying to remove cm0IF5KopLgxnJTUtfi403kJuMl2 in the FriendList

Here is my code:

```
export default function deletefriends(FriendsUID){

    const friendremove = async() =>{

        // get current users uid
        const Uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid

        // define the current users 
        const currentUID = firebase.firestore().collection('users').where(
            "UID", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get();
           
        // add the other users uid to current users friendlist
        currentUID.then((querySnapshot) => 

        {querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {doc.ref.update(

            {FriendsList:FriendsUID.delete()})
        })
    })
    

    }
```

How do I delete the FriendsUID?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are working with a ID map instead of an array, you will need to change out your code to (omitted unrelated parts):

```js
(doc) => {
  const friendsListMap = doc.get('FriendsList');
  delete friendsListMap[uidToDelete];
  return doc.ref.update({ FriendsList: friendsListMap });
}
```

or

```js
(doc) => {
  return doc.ref.update({
    [`FriendsList.${uidToDelete}`]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
  });
}
```

You should update your code to properly chain the Promises together (some are floating, use `querySnapshot.docs.map` and `Promise.all`) and consider making use of a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to perform these changes so you can ensure that data isn't wrongly being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to remove a single item from the `FriendsList` array, you need the `arrayRemove` operation. From the documentation on [updating items in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array):

```
await washingtonRef.update({
    regions: arrayRemove("east_coast")
});
```

Comment: Hi Frank I used `{FriendsList: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(FriendsUID)})` which it works, but it deleted everything in the FriendsList. I only need to remove one.  how can I do that ?

Comment: also, the FriendsList is was a map, and after ran the remove function, it became array, and became empty.